# Setting a default ErrorMessage for a custom ASP.NET MVC ValidationAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I've created a custom ASP.NET MVC ValidationAttribute and I'm trying to set my own default error message on it upon instantiation by passing a string to the base constructor:

```
public class BusinessLogicRegex : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "Invalid Password. {0}";
    private string _description;
    //Other private members
    ...

    public BusinessLogicRegex(string getMember, Type getMemberType, string descriptionMember, Type descriptionMemberType)
        : base(_defaultErrorMessage)
    {
        //Omitted the guts of initializing validation for brevity
        ...
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(ErrorMessage, _description);
    }
}
```

But when FormatErrorMessage is called, ErrorMessage is null. Why doesn't this `base(_defaultErrorMessage)` set the ErrorMessage property and how should I set it while still giving the user of this attribute the ability to override it?

**Edit - 2nd, cleaner Example:**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class TestValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    public TestValidator()
        : base("Test Error on {0}")
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(ErrorMessage, name);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }
}
```

Here again, FormatErrorMessage throws a null reference exception because `ErrorMessage` is null. However `ErrorMessageString` == "Test Error on {0}". So my mistake seems to be in thinking that calling `base("Test Error on {0}")` sets the ErrorMessage property. I don't understand this at all. Here how the base constructor describes its `errorMessage` parameter:

> The error message to associate with a validation control

Here is what MSDN says about the `ErrorMessageString` property:

> The error message string is obtained by evaluating the ErrorMessage property or by evaluating the ErrorMessageResourceType and ErrorMessageResourceName properties. The two cases are mutually exclusive. The second case is used if you want to display a localized error message.

Yet inside of FormatErrorMessage at runtime, `ErrorMessage`, `ErrorMessageResourceType` and  `ErrorMessageResourceName` are all null. So that description makes it sound like `ErrorMessageString` should also be null to me. This leaves me very confused about the usage and interaction between all of these properties and the constructor.

Comment: It should be `return String.Format(ErrorMessageString, name);`

Comment: No, I want to display _description there. I should put `name` in the default message somewhere though. But it's `ErrorMessage` that is null.

Comment: Which is exactly what that will do! Try it

Comment: Sorry, maybe I made it confusing by omitting code. `_description` is declared as a private instance member and initialized int he constructor. See my edit. The purpose of my validator is to go get a regular expression and a description of that expression from some specified class and method so that I can have it use the exact same validation expression that my business logic uses internally. I tried to only include what was relevant to the problem.

Comment: Yes I know! And when you use `: base(_defaultErrorMessage)` it assigns that message to the `ErrorMessageString` property. And then `String.Format(ErrorMessageString, name);` equates to `String.Format("Invalid Password. {0}", name)` which outputs "Invalid Password. xxx" where xxx is the value of `name`

Comment: If you want to also include `_description`, the make it say `private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "Invalid Password. {0} {1}";` and `return String.Format(ErrorMessageString, name, _description);`

Comment: I still don't see what name and _description have to do with `ErrorMessage` being null and causing a NullReferenceException. I added an additional example without _description to eliminate that from the equation. However, I noticed you're using `ErrorMessageString`, which is not null. I dug into the source code and arrived at an answer.

Comment: Because `ErrorMessage` is the value that your assign in `[Test(ErrorMessage = "...")]`. Again, when you use `: base("Test Error on {0}")` - its assigns that `ErrorMessageString`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I looked at the source code and I see why it's confusing. The ValidationAttribute class maintains a private _defaultErrorMessage field of its own. When I call base(errorMessage) it forwards my string as a lambda to the constructor that accepts a `Func<string> errorMessageAccessor` and sets that to a private `_errorMessageResourceAccessor` field. The `ErrorMessageString` getter first calls a method named `SetupResourceAccessor` where it determines whether to use

The `ErrorMessage` property is supported by a private `_errorMessage` field that appears to only be set by the `ErrorMessage` property setter. If `_errorMessageResourceAccessor` is null (which it is not in my case because I set it in the base constructor), this method will decide whether to set `_errorMessageResourceAccessor` to the default error message, a localized resource message, or the `ErrorMessage` property. **However, if it is not null, it will leave `_errorMessageResourceAccessor` set to its current value.** This is the case I am hitting. Lastly, the `ErrorMessage` property is supported by an _errorMessage field which appears to only get set by the `ErrorMessage` setter. The getter will return the default error message if `ErrorMessage` has not be explicitly set. Once the setter is called, it clears `_errorMessageResourceAccessor`.

So to try to summarize, calling `ErrorMessage` will give you the explicitly set error message or the default error message (which I actually don't know where it gets set. Maybe by an inheriting class?). Calling `ErrorMessageString` will give you a message in what looks to be the following order of presedence:

- The explicitly set ErrorMessage
- Localized value from ErrorMessageResourceName if it and ErrorMessageResourceType are set
- Constructor errorMessage string
- Default error message if nothing else is set